# create-react-app : npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for toidentifier@1.0.1

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I'm trying to create a new react project with create-react-app as usual :

```
npx create-react-app .
```

But I'm getting an error :

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for toidentifier@1.0.1.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
```

I've checked and the package toidentifier 1.0.1 is available in the repo.
I don't understand why I'm getting this error.

I am also able to get the same error when trying to `npm i` on an existing project that uses `react-scripts`.
The error is quite recent, I've never had any problem of this kind previously.

I'm using node 17.0.1 and npm 8.1.0
What could be wrong ?

Edit : I also tried with node 17.6.0 and npm 8.5 and the same thing happens

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this pls?

Comment: Yes, I managed to fix it ! I had to run `npm cache clean --force`. I guess something was wrong with the local package/dependency cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you encouter the same error, it's probably due to your local npm cache which isn't up to date and inconsistent.

Run `npm cache clean --force` to ensure that the package and dependencies lists will be updated.

This happened to me with the `toidentifier` package which is a low-level dependency used in various packages, including some webpack dependencies. It's likely that this error may occur with some other packages.